# Zend_Search_Lucene: UTF-8 madness

Tags: zend-framework, zend-search-lucene, zend-lucene

I hat some problems with Zend_Search_Lucene and non-english characters such as the german ÄÖÜ.
My database returns UTF-8 formatted strings so I thought everything will work just fine.

After having serious encoding problems I searched the web and found, that the following lines of code solved the problems for most people:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive ()
```

In fact, this did not solved my Problem.
Today I figured out a solution that works: (not the `utf8_decode`)

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('division', utf8_decode($contact->division)), 'utf-8');
```

Well, this is working perfectly fine, but frankly it looks quite odd. Why do I have to convert strings back and forth? 
Maybe I'm using Lucene wrong? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying and storing data are two different things . If your query is encoded in utf-8 then your data (document) should also be utf-8 encoded so to match the query .

Lastly

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('division', utf8_decode($contact->division)), 'utf-8');
```

shd be

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('division',$contact->division, 'utf-8'));
```

Comment: Oh no. So I simply passed the encoding argument to the wrong function?  That solved my problems! Thank you very much! I'm a bit ashamed of myself...